# How do I search for class element in Python?

Tags: python, html, class, element

I am new to Python and I've seen multiple tutorial videos online about web scraping.

This is the element from the targeted website:

```
<span class="status ng-binding"> 14 </span>
```

And this is my coding:

```
import requests
import bs4

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get('https://gleam.io/cevFk/castrio-october-streaming-pc-giveaway?gsr=cevFk-SxAtZtT4Ir', headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select("#status ng-binding"))
```

I'm trying to extract/output the number (which is 14) from the targeted website. Am I doing something wrong? Any answers is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

soup.find('span',{'class':'classname'},recursive=True).text

can add more attributes:
{'attr':'value','attr':'value'}

find_all() returns a list
recusrive searches in nested tags
ewrewr

Comment: Whenever I tried to printing "soup", it shows a string of "[]". Why does it do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the expected span is missing in the raw response.

You can verify by following these steps.

```
response = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

#print soup.prettify()
# print(soup.prettify())
print('title',soup.title)
print('fiind all spans', soup.find_all('span'))
```

Comment: Whenever I tried to printing "soup", it shows a string of "[]". Why does it do that?

Comment: [] is an empty list

Comment: It means there is no matches

Comment: Try with wnd without _ space symbol instead of space

Comment: I changed the "#status ng-binding" to "#status_ng-binding" and it still says "[]". And when I add "print(soup.find('span',{'class':'classname'},recursive=True))" it says "None"